# Need to run Fabric Script in Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, fabric

I am trying to automate the deployment procedure which copies the resources to destination folders and runs script automatically for which I have created this fabric file. Is it possible to run it from Eclipse IDE or is there any other way out also? Please help me with the steps. Also validate my fab file as I am new to fabric and python.

```
from fabric.api import *
import datetime

currentDate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

backupDir = "/tmp/kanwal_tmp/Backup_Dev-" + currentDate


env.use_ssh_config = True
env.hosts = ["Pfsv1d.nsroot.net"]
env.user = "ks073"
env.port = 22


def test():
    run("ls -al")

def DevDeploy():
    backupToBackupDir()
    copyToStagingFolder()
    deploymentInProgress()

print("Deployment " + currentDate + " complete")

#-------------------
# Utility functions
#-------------------

def backupToBackupDir():
    local("cp  /opt/gpf/cps/CPSCacheServer/lib/CPSCacheServer-1.0_A14-jar-with-dependencies.jar  backupDir")
    local("cp  /opt/gpf/cps/CPSCacheServer/lib/CPSCacheServer-1.0_A14.jar backupDir")
    local("cp  /opt/CPS/CPSWebServer/webapps/CPSWebService.war backupDir")

def copyToStagingFolder():
    local("cp /tmp/deploy_tmp/CPSCacheServer/* /opt/gpf/cps/install/CPSCacheServer/lib")
    local("cp /tmp/deploy_tmp/CPSCacheWebService/* /opt/CPSWebService/")

def deploymentInProgress():
    cd("/opt/pfApps/scripts/")
    run("./installCPSCacheServer.ksh")
    cd("/opt/gpf/cps/CPSCacheServer/bin/")
    run("./run_app.sh")
    cd("/opt/CPS/CPSWebServer/bin/" )
    run("./undeploy_CPSWebService_Node1.sh")
    run("./deploy_CPSWebService_Node1.sh")
```

Comment: Edited/Fixed your obvious copy/paste errors in the code. Have you tried to run a fab command via "run external command" in eclipse? Instead of using 'cp' I would use the 'rsync' extension from fabric. It has a tricky syntax but you will save a lot of time on the long run.

Comment: @tobltobs  Thanks for your reply.. could you please let me know the steps to run this script. I referred to earlier posts and there it was suggested to install pydev in Eclipse and from there one can execute fabfile..

Comment: No need for pydev. If you have installed fab you should be able to open a console, go to the directoy containing the above file (named fabfile.py) and execute is with a 'fab backupToBackupDir'. 'fab' is an executable installed somewhere on your system. You can enter this command as "External tool" in Eclispe.

Comment: No I have not installed Fab and nither I know a wayout to install it as I am new to it.. if you could please guide me through.